# Access to objects that are not defined without using a try-catch block

Tags: javascript, try-catch

I want to access to objects that are `undefined` without using the try-catch.

**This is my object:**

```
var obj = {
  par1 : {
    par2 : "Hello"
  }
}
```

If I want to print `parametro2` I can do:

```
console.log(obj.par1.par2);
```

and it works.

---

But if `par1` id `UNDEFINED` it crashes if I don't use a try-catch.

---

```
obj.par1 = undefined;
  try{
    console.log(obj.par1.par2)
  } catch(e){
    console.log("Error" + e);
  }
```

is there a way to handle this  `without` using a `try-catch` block ?

Comment: What value do you expect, when `par1` is `undefined`?

Comment: I don't want it to crash without using a try-catch

Comment: Then it has to be evaluated to something, right? What do you want that "something" to be?

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like

```
if (obj.par1 && obj.par1.par2) {
    console.log(obj.par1.par2);
}
```

Comment: ok, but I need to do it in the best way, because I could have even deeper objects

Comment: My first instinct is to ask you why you need to do this. This seems like a problem that you shouldn't be having, and that could be solved by re-factoring other parts of your code base. In any case, however, I'll do my best to answer your question. The next thing that comes to mind is doing something like this. You can nest objects arbitrarily this way. http://jsfiddle.net/z3YET/ But again, I wouldn't recommend this. You shouldn't really have to do something like this.

Comment: _"How can I do this thing, without using the two technologies that are provided to do it?"_ Why do you arbitrarily reject them?

Answer (score 1):

```
var nestedObject = {
  n1: {
    n2: {
      n3: {
        prop: "true"
      }
    }
  }
};



function getNested(obj, key) {
  var bits = key.split(".");
  var o = obj;
  var result;
  var len = bits.length;

  for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    var bit = bits[i];
    console.log(o);
    if (!o[bit]) {
      return undefined;
    }
    o = o[bit];
  }
  return o;
}

alert(getNested(nestedObject, 'n1.n2.n3.prop'));
```

Comment: Interesting, generalized approach. Variable result does not appear to be used, though.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to do this a lot, I suggest that you write a helper function, which could be something like this:

```
function getKey(obj, keys) {
  keys = keys.split('.');
  var value = obj;
  if (obj == null) {
    return obj;
  }
  do {
    value = value[keys.shift()];
  } while (value != null && keys.length !== 0);
  return value;
}

var obj = {
  a: {
    b: 'hello',
    c: {
      d: 'world'
    }
  },
  e: 'foo'
};

getKey(obj, 'a.b');    // returns 'hello'
getKey(obj, 'a.c');    // returns { d: 'world' }
getKey(obj, 'a.c.d');  // returns 'world'
getKey(obj, 'e');      // returns 'foo'
getKey(obj, 'f');      // returns undefined
getKey(obj, 'z.x.y');      // returns undefined
getKey(undefined, 'f');// returns undefined
getKey(null, 'f');     // returns null
```

I hope this helps. I have only test this with the values I provided but it should work fine.